# to_csv function with delimeter as pipe giving issues

Tags: python, pandas

I am running this

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick,paul', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
delimiter='|'
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\mpaul\\workspace\\out\\tre\\test.csv', index=False, date_format='%m-%d-%Y', sep=delimiter)
```

Output

[image]

I want

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is an issue with `excel`. If you open the file in a text editor (notepad, sumblime) you'll see the file is written **exactly** as you want. The issue is that when `excel` tries to open the file it sees a `,` and then tries to infer that's the delimiter.

Comment: Which you can get around by importing the file into excel and specifying the delimiter.

Comment: thanks guys yeah it is as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that csv files are interpreted with commas as the separator (as its name suggests: *comma separated values*). The `to_csv()` method just writes down your data with the separator specified. If you open the file with a plain text editor you may find the result you want. I've tested your code and get the same result, but when I open the output with the Notepad I see this

[image: Output with the Notepad]